# Accessing IExplorerCommandProvider from IShellFolder

Tags: windows-shell, windows-explorer

I am writing an Explorer extension for Vista and Windows 7. I read that if you are making a namespace extension you can provide your own commands using **IExplorerCommandProvider**. This is done in response to **IShellFolder::CreateViewObject**.

I am not writing a namespace extension, but a toolbar that lets you perform operations in Explorer. So I need to get **IExplorerCommandProvider** from an existing **IShellFolder**.

I get **IShellView** from the **IShellBrowser**, then I convert it to **IFolderView**, then I get **IShellFolder**. So far so good. I get a valid folder pointer.

This however doesn't work:
pShellFolder->CreateViewObject(NULL,IID_IExplorerCommandProvider,&p); // returns E_NOINTERFACE

I tried passing different values for the **hwnd** parameter of **CreateViewObject**, starting with the file pane and going all the way up to the top level Explorer window, and none of them worked.

So my questions are:
1) Do regular file system folders even support **IExplorerCommandProvider**?
2) If they do, how do I get my hands on that interface?

Thanks
Ivo